# localStorage with different people

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I have a page which records data from different employees. One of the things is to record the entry and exit from them. I can record these data with localStorage, but this works for all the people the same. Tried to used different names for the the localStorage item, but it is not working when I change the employee. Can someone give me assistance to accomplish this?
This is the code working for all the same:

```
var entradasaida = 0;

entradasaida = localStorage.getItem("entradasaida");


if(entradasaida == 0){



var time = $('#time').val();
var time2 = $('#time2').val();
var datetime = new Date();
var year = datetime.getFullYear();
var month = datetime.getMonth()+1;
if(month < 10){
month = "0"+month
}
var day = datetime.getDay()+1;
if(day < 10){
day = "0"+day
}
var date = new Date(year+"-"+month+"-"+day+" "+time+":"+time2); 

var mills = date.getTime();

var timeE = localStorage.getItem("horas");
var time2E = localStorage.getItem("mins");

alert(timeE);

localStorage.setItem("horas", time);
localStorage.setItem("mins", time2);
localStorage.setItem("entradasaida",1);
localStorage.setItem("millsEnt",mills);

if(timeE != null){

$('#horas_button').text("Saida");
$('#time, #time2').val("");
$('#entrada').text(timeE+":"+time2E);
}

} else{

var horasEnt = localStorage.getItem("horas");
var minsEnt = localStorage.getItem("mins");
var entrada = localStorage.getItem("millsEnt");

localStorage.setItem("entradasaida",0);
$('#horas_button').text("Entrada");

var time = $('#time').val();
var time2 = $('#time2').val();
var datetime = new Date();

var year = datetime.getFullYear();
var month = datetime.getMonth()+1;
if(month < 10){
month = "0"+month
}
var day = datetime.getDay()+1;
if(day < 10){
day = "0"+day
}
var date1 = new Date(year+"-"+month+"-"+day+" "+time+":"+time2); 


var millssai = date1.getTime();
$('#millssai').text(millssai);

var totMills = (millssai - entrada)

var horas = time - horasEnt;
var mins = time2 - minsEnt;
if(mins < 0){
mins = mins*(-1);
mins = mins.toFixed(2);
horas = horas-1;
}
var totHoras = horas+":"+mins
$('#totHoras').text(totHoras);
$('#mills').text(totMills);
$('#time, #time2').val("");
$('#entrada').text(totHoras);
}
```

};

If I add this variable `var func = $("#func option:selected").text();`and add `func`to all local storage items it messes up everything.

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is. What does "messes up everything" mean? What do you mean by "when I change the employee"?

Comment: When I add `func`to all localStorage items.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**
Got it working finally. Here's the full code:

```
    var func= "";
    var entradasaida = 0;


    $( "#func" ).change(function() {
  func = $("#func option:selected").text();

  entradasaida = localStorage.getItem(func+"entradasaida");
  if(entradasaida == 1){
        $('#horas_button').text("Saida");
        var horasEnt = localStorage.getItem(func+"horas");
        var minsEnt = localStorage.getItem(func+"mins");
        $('#entrada').text(horasEnt+":"+minsEnt);
    } else{
        $('#horas_button').text("Entrada");
        $('#entrada').text("Horário");
    }
  });


    $(".inputs").keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
    $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
    }
    });
    $(".inputs1").keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
    $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
    }
    });

    var callback = function() {
        alert(func);


    entradasaida = localStorage.getItem(func+"entradasaida");

    if(entradasaida == 0){



    var time = $('#time').val();
    var time2 = $('#time2').val();
    var datetime = new Date();
    var year = datetime.getFullYear();
    var month = datetime.getMonth()+1;
    if(month < 10){
    month = "0"+month
    }
    var day = datetime.getDay()+1;
    if(day < 10){
    day = "0"+day
    }
    var date = new Date(year+"-"+month+"-"+day+" "+time+":"+time2); 

    var mills = date.getTime();

    var timeE = localStorage.getItem(func+"horas");
    var time2E = localStorage.getItem(func+"mins");

    alert(timeE);

    localStorage.setItem(func+"horas", time);
    localStorage.setItem(func+"mins", time2);
    localStorage.setItem(func+"entradasaida",1);
    localStorage.setItem(func+"millsEnt",mills);



    $('#horas_button').text("Saida");
    $('#time, #time2').val("");
    $('#entrada').text(timeE+":"+time2E);


    } else{

    var horasEnt = localStorage.getItem(func+"horas");
    var minsEnt = localStorage.getItem(func+"mins");
    var entrada = localStorage.getItem(func+"millsEnt");


    localStorage.setItem(func+"entradasaida",0);

    var time = $('#time').val();
    var time2 = $('#time2').val();
    var datetime = new Date();

    var year = datetime.getFullYear();
    var month = datetime.getMonth()+1;
    if(month < 10){
    month = "0"+month
    }
    var day = datetime.getDay()+1;
    if(day < 10){
    day = "0"+day
    }
    var date1 = new Date(year+"-"+month+"-"+day+" "+time+":"+time2); 


    var millssai = date1.getTime();
    $('#millssai').text(millssai);

    var totMills = (millssai - entrada)

    var horas = time - horasEnt;
    var mins = time2 - minsEnt;
    if(mins < 0){
    mins = mins*(-1);
    mins = mins.toFixed(2);
    horas = horas-1;
    }
    var totHoras = horas+":"+mins
    $('#totHoras').text(totHoras);
    $('#mills').text(totMills);
    $('#time, #time2').val("");
    $('#entrada').text(totHoras);

    $('#horas_button').text("Entrada");
    }   
};

$("horas_button").keypress(function() {
    callback();
});

$('#horas_button').click(callback);
```